# Graphql Delete operation using mutation

Tags: javascript, graphql, mutation

I'm trying to create delete operation. I have a user and tasks to do. Each user has a list of tasks assigned. Here is my code of delete operation:

```
const Mutation = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Mutation',
    fields: {
        deleteUser: {
            type: UserType,
            args: {
                id: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID) }
            },
            resolve(parent, args){
                var id = (args.id).toString()
                let todos = Todo.find({ user_id: id });
                let user = User.findById(args.id);
                todos.remove();
                user.findOneAndRemove();
                return todos;
            }
        }
    }
})
```

And here are my defined types:

```
const ToDoType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'todoItem',
    fields: () => ({
        id: {type: GraphQLID},
        title: {type: GraphQLString},
        completed: {type: GraphQLBoolean},
        user: {
            type: UserType,
            resolve(parent, args){
                return User.findById(parent.user_id);
            }
        }
    })
});

const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'user',
    fields: () => ({
        id: {type: GraphQLID},
        name: {type: GraphQLString},
        email: {type: GraphQLString},
        login: {type: GraphQLString},
        todos: {
            type: new GraphQLList(ToDoType),
            resolve(parent, args){
                return Todo.find({ user_id: parent.id })
            }
        }
    })
});
```

The problem is that while deleting user I want to delete all his "to do's" but according to what I put in return I can delete only one thing.. So now I have "return todos" and it deletes only todo assigned to user, but not the user. When I put there "return user" it will delete only user without his tasks. How can I delete user and his tasks at once?

Comment: "*according to what I put in return I can delete only one thing.*" - not sure what you mean. Your code does delete both things (though it might need some `await`s). Are you asking about the graphql schema structure?

Comment: `User.findById(args.id).findOneAndRemove();` is weird. Do you really need to find it twice?

Comment: @Bergi I meant that nothing is deleted from my database. All the records stay the same as if nothing was removed

Comment: So `todos.remove();` and/or `user.findOneAndRemove();` don't work? What do they do? Can you share their code? Do they throw any errors? Either way, this should have nothing to do with "*what I put in return*".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code as shown appears to actually mutate the data to delete both the user, and all their todos. I believe the confusion you're having is that the mutation operation has the "type" (i.e. what it will return) of `User`. That is therefore what you'd need to return from the mutation function.

More conceptually, it *might* be a good idea to return from that both the user and all their data, so that if the API user wanted to capture some or all of that, they could, though given privacy implications that might not be ideal. An alternative approach would be to have the mutation just return a success-or-failure status.

Comment: when i try to do something like this: 
`deleteUser: {
            type: UserType,
            args: {
                id: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID) }
            },
            resolve(parent, args){
                var id = (args.id).toString()
                let todos = Todo.find({ user_id: id });
                let user = User.findById(args.id);
                todos.remove();
                user.remove();
                return true;
            }
        },` 
it doesnt return anything.. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You are telling GraphQL that the `deleteUser` field returns (the `type` value) a `UserType` but your `resolve` method is returning a boolean. You need to make them match.

Comment: Okay, thanks @Ed, I understand. Nevertheless I've got one question. Does resolve always need to return something? Do I always need to specify type while doing for example delete operation?

Comment: Yes, that's the GraphQL idiom. Fields always have a type. You need to go through this tutorial if you haven't already: https://graphql.org/graphql-js/